# Rails exclude multiple NOT IN

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to exclude any records if they contain any part of my `exclude` array. So an item can be **'Item name (BSE)'** or **'Item name (B)'** etc.

So far i have the following which does not work:

```
exclude = ['(BSE)', '(B)', '(SED)', '(DES)', '(VCS)']
@results = Results.where('results.item NOT IN (?)', exclude)
```

Is there a way to do this without listing each item in a LIKE statement or similar? My exclude array will grow over time so adding records to the array would be ideal rather then writing individual like statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```rb
where = (1..exclude.count).to_a.fill('item NOT LIKE ?').join(' AND ')
@results = Results.where(where, *exclude.map {|x| "%#{x}%"})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just another possible solution, multiple chained `where` clauses are joined with `AND` by Rails.

```
exclude = %w[(BSE) (B) (SED) (DES) (VCS)]
exclude.each do |ex|
  @results = Results.where('item NOT LIKE ?', ex)
end
```